# TableViewController: Replace Table with Login or Error-Screen

Tags: swift, view, tableview, screen, info

what is best practice to display a full-screen info in a TableViewController instead of the table on certain events, e.g. a "Login Required"-Label with an ImageView and a Login-Button?

I think, adding the content in a cell and hide all other cells should work but would not be the best solution.

It should look similar to the "Cant Connect to App Store" Screen:
There should be a label and a button and the view should not be scrollable!
[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is to use a regular UIViewController with a UITableView and a UIView.

The UIView can contain whatever content you want to display when not displaying the table view. Then you simply hide or show the table view.

When setting up your UIViewController, you will need to make sure to indicate that it implements the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols, and set your view controller as the data source and delegate for your table view. This is pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks for the response, sounds like an approach. The disadvantage is in my opinion, that it's not very well to reuse, e.g. if you wanna use an "Authorization-Error-View" for many ViewControllers. Also, if you wanna have more Info-States, say a "No Internet Connection" or Empty-State, there have to be all these views in every controller.... So, I'm looking forward to other ideas, but thanks for response, its a good direction!